# KQL ingest query not working with 'Where' statement

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I'm trying to ingest into a testing table in Kusto.

The table is created using this syntax:

```
.create table testing(id: string, label: string)
```

I'm trying to insert inline into this table using the below query:

```
.ingest inline into table testing <|
"5671343d-8eaa-4939-8225-cb17805868d8","2"
| where id != "5671343d-8eaa-4939-8225-cb17805868d8"
```

When I try to ingest it normally, it is working. But, when i use the Where statement, to make sure I do not ingest duplicates, the query is failing to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your query is that the `where` clause is not valid in an inline ingestion command. The `where` clause is used to filter data in a Kusto query, but it is not supported in an inline ingestion command. To avoid ingesting duplicates, you can use the [extent tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/extent-tags)

- In this approach, you can ingest the data along with the tags.

**example**:

```
.ingest ... with (tags = '["ingest-by:2016-02-17"]')
```

- To prevent duplicate ingestion, you can use `ingestIfNotExists` in the .ingest command

**example**:

```
.ingest ... with (ingestIfNotExists = '["2016-02-17"]')
```

Refer **MS doc** on [handling duplicate rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates) in azure data explorer.